# MySQL update table using import data from Text file

Tags: mysql, sql

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\dummy data.txt' INTO TABLE mmc_avado.avado_mmc_file FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I have this query to import date from text file to mysql.
But I want....

1. If data in mysql and text file are same then do not import that line.
2. If data in text file has some updated fields which is not in mysql for the same row. Like 
   both has that row but text file has some updated fields.

Then how we perform this. Please help.

Comment: It's not the job of `load data` to that filtering for you. load into a temporary table, then use `insert ... select from ...` and do the filtering there.

Comment: @MarcB: Yet `LOAD DATA` recognises both `REPLACE` and `IGNORE` keywords to handle duplicate key errors...

Answer (score 1):

You should import the data into a staging (possibly temporary) table then add the new data into the target table like this:

```
INSERT
INTO    mmc_avado.avado_mmc_file
SELECT  *
FROM    staging_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  col1 = VALUES(col1),
        col2 = VALUES(col2),
        ...
```

Comment: If a suitable unique key has been defined, why not use `LOAD DATA REPLACE ...` ?

Comment: @eggyal: `UPDATE` logic might be more complex than that, but this is a viable option too of course, if a mere `REPLACE` is what the op needs.

Comment: @eggyal: also, `REPLACE` is a `DELETE` followed by `INSERT` which is harder on I/O, might fire wrong triggers and/or fail on foreign key violations